# How to repeat saved recorded keyboard macro in Sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2

I can record keyboard macro by ctrl+q and after that I can play it with ctrl+shift+q. I can also save recorded macro to the file. However if I save it, record another macro and open my macro again then I can not replay it with ctrl+shift+q as it replays only the macro that was recorded to the buffer. So the question is: can I put opened from the file macro to the buffer and replay it with shift+ctrl+q?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ctrl+Shift+Q` only works for the most recently recorded macro. However, if you would like to assign your desired macro to a key binding, here is how you would do that:

1. Open User Key Bindings (Preferences > Key Bindings > User)
2. Add this key binding:

   { "keys": ["keyboard-shortcut"],
       "command": "run_macro_file",
       "args": { "file": "Packages/User/name-of-macro.sublime-macro" }
   }

Answer (score 2):

Or just record the saved macro, this way you can use Ctrl+Shift+Q, since now the saved macro is the most recently recorded macro.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for

Comment: This is the best answer. Annoying there isn't a repeat to end of file option like text editors have had for generations but this is the next best thing and just saved me lots of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once you've recorded your macro using Ctr+Alt+Q,
you can use this package to repeat the macro until the end of file:
[Repeat Macro Sublime package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Repeat%20Macro)